# Remote Desktop connection on Android tablet

Tags: android, tablet, remote-desktop

We are working on Android tablet app. This app require remote desktop connection support for connect **System to Tablet** or **Tablet to Tablet**. How can we achieve this? Is there any SDK available for this work? Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(v=vs.85) also there are a few apps out there that already do this but of course they cost some change. This sounds pretty interesting tho, I might try it, the hard part is creating the webservice... http://www.packetizer.com/ipmc/t120/primer/

Comment: Hi Arun,,, did u get any solution?